# My header image is following the scroll down

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a side left menu for mobile but I have an issue :
When I scroll my content, my header image follows the scroll and hides some content. I need my header to be fixed in it's place...

Here is a demonstration of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/th46k/7/

My *Html*:

```
<header id="top">   
    <span id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></span>
</header>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="menubar">
        <div id="button">Menu</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

And this is my **CSS**:

```
 * {
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
 }
 #top {
     width:226px;
     margin:10px auto 10px auto;
 }
 #logo {
     float:left;
 }
 #menubar {
     width:100%;
     background-color:#444;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 10px;
 }
 #button {
     cursor:pointer;
 }
 #menu, #right {
 }
 #menu li a {
     padding: 10px;
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 #right {
     width:100%;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: 5;
     position: fixed;
     overflow: scroll;
     left: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     moz-box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     o-box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     box-shadow: -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }
 #right p {
     padding: 10px;
 }
 #menu {
     float:left;
     width: 350px;
     height: 100%;
 }
 #menu li {
     background-color:#444;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
 }
```

Comment: Is there styling added to your header tag?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example related to your requirement. When you scroll the page the header area will stick to the top. Do some changes as per your requirement. Hope it will help you.

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ivolij/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you for your answer naresh kumar. But I already tried what you have in your example, but dont work in mine! If you try what you have in my jsfiddle you´ll see that my header disappear!